# ajaxForm not working if there is a event.preventDefault function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-forms-plugin

Good day guys, I'm trying to submit a form with a file using jQuery Form Plugin, and I'm validating the form using HTML5 attributes that's why I've added a 'event.preventDefault();'

The problem is, it's not working and it's not displaying any error message.

Here's the code

```
function showResponse(responseText){
    alert(responseText);
}
function beforeSub(){
    alert("called");
}
$('#prodFormBtn').click(function(){

$("#addProductForm").ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit: beforeSub,
    success: showResponse
}).submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  function showResponse(responseText){
     alert(responseText);
  }

  function beforeSub(){
    alert("called");
  }

  $("#addProductForm").ajaxForm(showResponse);
});
```

Function `ajaxForm` make interaction though the form by ajax, you should just set success event handler (`showResponse`).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using HTML5 validation, then that validation is part of what the browser does on form submission. Don't `preventDefault()` on form submission if you want the HTML5 validation to fire.